# how to use Elastic Search nested queries by object key instead of object property

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery

Following the Elastic Search example in [this article](http://conan.is/blogging/weighted-elasticsearch.html) for a nested query, I noticed that it assumes the nested objects are inside an ARRAY and that queries are based on some object PROPERTY:

```
{
    nested_objects: [   <== array
         { name: "x", value: 123 },
         { name: "y", value: 456 }  <== "name" property searchable
    ]
}
```

But what if I want nested objects to be arranged in key-value structure that gets updated with new objects, and I want to search by the KEY? example:

```
{
    nested_objects: {   <== key-value, not array
         "x": { value: 123 },
         "y": { value: 456 }  <== how can I search by "x" and "y" keys?
         "..."  <=== more arbitrary keys are added now and then
    ]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Simply search with `nested_objects.x.value: 123`

Comment: That is not what I need. Note I wrote " arbitrary keys", i.e. I don't know in advance that "x" and "y" or any other key actually exists. I'm trying to answer the question: "get all objects taht contain nested object's keys that match a certain term"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so my final solution after some ES insights is as follows:
1. The fact that my object keys "x", "y", ... are arbitrary causes a mess in my index mapping. So generally speaking, it's not a good ES practice to plan this kind of structure... So for the sake of mappings, I resort to the structure described in the "Weighted tags" article:

```
{ "name":"x", "value":123 },
{ "name":"y", "value":456 },
...
```

2. This means that, when it's time to update the value of the sub-object named "x", I'm having a harder (and slower) time finding it: I first need to query the entire top-level object, traverse the sub objects until I find one named "x" and then update its value. Then I update the entire sub-object array back into ES.
3. The above approach also causes concurrency issues in case I have multiple processes updating the same index. ES has optimistic locking I can use to retry when needed, or, I can queue updates and handle them serially

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this using the `query_string` query, like this:

```
GET my_index/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query":"nested_objects.\\*.value:123"
    }
  }
}
```

It will try to match the `value` field of any sub-field of `nested_objects`.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for: I don't know the value "123" in advance. I'm trying to query only by "x" or "y" and then use their "value" in my scoring function